# exception in accessing vector while accessing elements

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, vector

I am trying to tone my concepts on core java and multithreading.  While reading some book I found 
the below code may throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the vector is accessed in some way by another thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
   doSomething(vector.get(i));
}
```

I really tried a lot but not able to figure out how?
Can any one help me on this.

Comment: From this code alone, it's impossible to say.  What does `doSomething` do?  Are there any other threads running that might access `vector` in parallel?

Comment: If another thread removes an element of the vector while you are processing it, you could get that exception

Comment: `vector.get(i)` will throw exception if the `i` is greater than the current element count of the vector .

Comment: One thread is running that code. It checks that `i` is less than the size of the vector. Before it does the `vector.get()`, some other thread could remove an element in the vector. When the first thread gets to the `get()` it will fail because there are no longer that many elements in the vector.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the example has only this snippt, 
i got the point now. Initially i was thinking this  code alone can throw this Exception. now i realize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vector has all fields syncronized . In this case we perform operations such as getting the vertor's size and than we try to access the `i` element later. All of them are synchonized but they are distributed in time, there are no synchronization between we get the `vertor.size()` and `vector.get(i)` so our current thread can be suspended and vector can be modified by another thread so it is possible that the vector's size will be changed. For example:

```
public class TestClass {
    private static final Vector vector = new Vector();

    public static void iterate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            doSomething(vector.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main (String... args) {
            //initialize vector and fill it
        new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                iterate();
            }
        }, "A").start();

        new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vector.clear();
            }
        }, "B").start();
    }

    private static void doSomething(Object object) {
        //DO SMTHNG.
    }
}
```

In this case while thread `A` will iterate over the vector the thread `B` can clear it so the `i` can be more than new vector's size (in this case 0). The simplest way to fix this is to cover `iterate()` method body with `synchronized (vector) {...}` block or use more sophisticated approach.

Comment: thanks a lot.
I got the reason. as i have mentioned in the question comment, i was thinking that code alone can lead to the exception.